# Best solution for finding time difference in php with datetime with am pm?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo

I am developing a travel portal for a company, but having difficulties in finding time differences.

Using the same stored dates in date time format of am/pm I have to...

- find running cabs
- using those same dates I have to calculate the time difference between trip start and trip end
- finally, how much time left to start trip

And yes, one more thing; since the travel company operates in India and follows 12 hour time format it becomes more difficult for me to calculate the time difference.

Comment: PHP's [DateTime](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) as well as MySQL's [Date and Time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use date_diff function as below, it allows am/pm as well.

```
print_r( date_diff( date_create('2015-10-04 01:00:00am'), date_create('2015-10-04 02:00:00pm')) );
```

Output -->

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0 // corresponds to years
    [m] => 0 // corresponds to months
    [d] => 0 // corresponds to days
    [h] => 13 // corresponds to hours
    [i] => 0 // corresponds to minutes
    [s] => 0 // corresponds to seconds
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

From DateInterval Object you can get time difference.

```
$datetime_diff_Obj = date_diff( date_create('2015-10-04 01:00:00am'), date_create('2015-10-04 02:00:00pm'));

echo $datetime_diff_Obj->h; // hours
echo $datetime_diff_Obj->i ;// minutes
echo $datetime_diff_Obj->s; // seconds
```

To get difference in hours please use below code

```
$time_diff = (round ( abs ( strtotime('2015-10-04 01:00:00am') - strtotime('2015-10-02 02:00:00pm') ) /3600 ) );
echo $time_diff." hrs ";
```

output ->

```
35 hrs
```

Comment: what about this ?    $datetime_diff_Obj = date_diff( date_create('2015-11-09 11:00:00 am'), date_create('2015-11-10 11:00:00 am'));

echo $datetime_diff_Obj->h; // hours    its gives me 0

Comment: what about this ?    $datetime_diff_Obj = date_diff( date_create('2015-11-09 11:00:00 am'), date_create('2015-11-10 11:00:00 am'));

echo $datetime_diff_Obj->h; // hours    i want to get all difference in hours only not in days like after 47 hours not 1 day and 23 hours

Comment: @AnilBairwa - please check I have added code for difference in hours.

Comment: thanks it solved my purpose